# How to setup Play Framework 1.2.7 in Inttellij IDE

Tags: playframework, frameworks, playframework-1.x

I have a project use Play Framework 1.2.7 but  Inttellij IDE 13.1 no support and help me coding !![RED line is Error !][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ play idea

Open intellij and File > import project > Create project from existing sources > next > next ... finish

Then you can no more see Red line on your code.